# Permissions Query

Tags: permissions

I thought I understood how permissions work in Linux, until I became aware of this situation.

I have a subfolder, *oddball* that contains files with following permissions:

```
ls -aRl /mnt/oddball
/mnt/oddball:
total 120
drwx------ 2 bendipa bendipa  4096 Aug 27 00:16 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root    root     4096 Jul  1 15:51 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bendipa bendipa    12 Aug 27 00:16 Adoc.txt
-rwx------ 1 bendipa bendipa 12655 Aug 26 18:16 .IntBnkDet.doc.pgp
-rwx------ 1 bendipa bendipa 14550 Aug 26 19:04 .PersonalDetail.odt.pgp
-rwx------ 1 bendipa bendipa 76357 Aug 15 15:43 .StatePensionGateway.doc.pgp
```

The problem is every time I make a new file within */mnt/oddball* it assumes permissions shown as with the file **Adoc.txt**, whereas I assumed files would take permissions from their parent folder; in this case *oddball*'s are shown as the first of the output line permissions  listed. I note the parent folder of *oddball*, */mnt* is root owned and shows permissions different to *oddball*, but would not expect those to have any effect on *oddball*'s files.

Of course it's easy enough to change the permissions of new files in */mnt oddball* in the terminal, but having to do so each time a file is created is a bit tedious. Or is this a necessity in Linux?

Comment: What filesystem is on the media mounted at `/mnt/oddball`?

Comment: Sorry if I've confused you. But */mnt/oddball* is simply a convenient container for certain files that I transferred there. It's not on a partition mounted from an external drive, and its  ext4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Permissions are not inherited from the parent folder.

On a normal filesystem, new files are created with mode 0666 (`rw-rw-rw-`) but *modified* by the `umask` value (inverted).

So, for example:

```
$ umask 0
$ touch foo
$ ls -l foo
-rw-rw-rw- 1 sweh sweh 0 Aug 26 21:14 foo

$ umask 022
$ touch bar
$ ls -l bar
-rw-r--r-- 1 sweh sweh 0 Aug 26 21:14 bar

$ umask 0222
$ echo hello > baz
$ ls -l baz       
-r--r--r-- 1 sweh sweh 6 Aug 26 21:15 baz
```

We can see that the `umask` value determines the permissions that the new file is created with.

To explain the numbers:

```
r=4
w=2
x=1
```

Each file has permissions for "owner", "group", "world".  If you look at the number in Octal then you can break it down.

eg a permission of 0123 would mean

```
owner = 1 ==> --x
group = 2 ==> -w-
world = 3 ==> -wx
```

And we can see this:

```
$ chmod 0123 foo 
$ ls -l foo
---x-w--wx 1 sweh sweh 0 Aug 26 21:27 foo
```

A `umask` value determines the bits to *keep*.  So determine the actual creation mode you take the 0666 and do a bitwise AND with the *negation* of the umask.

So if the `umask` is 0022 then the negation is 0755 and `0666 AND 0755` is 0644, which leads to the `rw-r--r--` permission we saw earlier.

However there are some complications.

First is that to *get* to the file you need permissions along the whole directory path.  So, in your example, even though `Adoc.txt` has world read permissions no one else can see the file because the directory blocks them from getting that far.

So *effective* permissions depend on the permissions on the whole directory tree, as well as the permissions on the file.

For example:

```
$ sudo ls -al X
total 8
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Aug 26 21:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Aug 26 21:18 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    6 Aug 26 21:19 y
```

The permissions on `y` says everyone can read it, but if I try...

```
$ cat X/y
cat: X/y: Permission denied
```

That's because the *directory* permission is blocking me.

You need `x` permissions on a directory to read files inside it.

```
$ sudo chmod a+x X

$ ls -ld X
drwx--x--x 2 root root 4096 Aug 26 21:19 X/

$ cat X/y
hello
```

Another complication is if you use a non-native file system (eg NTFS, or SMB).  The mount flags can override the Unix permissions just because the original filesystem doesn't understand unix permissions.  But that's likely not the case in your question.

Comment: Some useful stuff. I think the first line of your answer is the all-important one. But I'm not sure why you are demonstrating with umask, when I thought  chmod was the standard command for changing permissions, with umask being used for NTFS permissions.

Comment: The `umask` determines the permissions of new files.  It's what was used to set the permissions on your `Adhoc.txt` file.  `chmod` lets you _change_ permissions on existing files.  `umask` determines the permissions on newly created files.

Comment: What, for root owned files/folders also? I know that *mnt/oddball* shows myself as user:owner, but originally it was root-owned when I created it.

Comment: Yes, even for root.